# Why does my kernel in Juypter lab die when i import tensorflow on mac m1

Tags: python, tensorflow, kernel, jupyter, apple-m1

When I run import tensorflow an error occurs which say that my kernel have died.

I have tried `conda install nomkl` but doesnt seems to work.

I have also tried deleting `ibiomp5.dylib` file and it doesnt work.

So now I am clueless on what I should do.

Would like some help with this

Comment: Try to import it from IPython console. Does it errour out after import? If so you can narrow down the issue and exclude jupyter-lab tag (and add IPython).

Comment: Yes, it does error (kernel died, restarting) after importing tensorflow in IPython console. What do you mean by narrow down the issue and exclude juypter-lab tag?

Comment: I mean that the problem is not in JupyterLab (since you confirmed that it errors out when not using JupyterLab at all). I would suggest to swap the `jupyter-lab` tag to `ipython` (or better, try to import from standard Python and if it is still a problem, change the tag to `python`) - this way the question will show up in feeds of users who are using IPython/Python.

Comment: Oh okay will do